# Use PostBackUrl to submit specific part of form

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have an ASP.NET webforms application and a requirement to add a form to a page which will be posted to an external URL, a payment processing provider. The form needs to include specific hidden inputs, one of which is a hashed string representation of the form data.

I understand given limitations of webforms I can't nest a second form within the main `<form runat="server" />`. However, I don't have the option to locate my form outside of that main form (due to the CMS this site is built into).

I know I can use an ASP.NET Button control with a PostBackUrl attribute which allows the form to post to a specific URL. However, this posts every form element on the page, including __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTTARGET etc.

This is not desired behaviour. I only want to submit specific data. Also, this makes it difficult (impossible?) to generate the hash representation of the form because this would have to include viewstate etc.

I also don't have the option to post the data from the code behind because the client is expected to continue their interaction at the target URL.

Do I have any options here? This must be possible, but an internet search has returned very little.

**UPDATE**: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to utilize ajax. Simply use it to post data you need and you don't even have to redirect or anything. You'd be in control of literally everything (well as long as the user has javascript turned on, of course).

Comment: Thank you, but this can't be a JS-only solution. It's unreasonable to restrict online payments to only those with JS enabled.

Comment: @getsetcode, well in that case I'm afraid you've just hit a limitation of webforms.. Have you considered switching to MVC? It would probably make your life much easier.

Comment: I would dearly love to but the CMS we're using constrains me to webforms. It's astonishing that there is no answer to this but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax update panel for this .
  put asp:scriptManager on page

```
    <asp:scriptManager></asp:scriptManager>

   <asp:updatePanel runat="server">
      <contentTemplate>
              your controls to be submitted to next page   
            <asp:button><asp:button>
      </contentTemplate>
   </asp:updatePanel>
```

and put other controls outside updatePanel.

Comment: Thank you, but this can't be a JS-only solution. It's unreasonable to restrict online payments to only those with JS enabled.